# Converter Gson para List<Object>

Tags: android, json, gson

Estou com começando a aprender a usar a biblioteca Gson no meu código e preciso criar uma lista de objetos a partir de um arquivo Json.

```
Json: [{"id":1,"cat":"teste","icone":"icone"},{"id":2,"cat":"teste2","icone":"icone2"}]
```

desse arquivo dois Objetos (CategoriaItem) são gerados e adicionado a lista utilizando esse código:

```
    public static List<CategoriaItem> jsonCategoria(String json) {
    List<CategoriaItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonBase = new JSONArray(json);


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonBase.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonBase.getJSONObject(i);
            CategoriaItem categoria = new CategoriaItem(object);
            list.add(categoria);
        }
```

Quais ajustes deveria realizar para criar essa mesma lista utilizando a biblioteca Gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implemente `Serializable` na classe CategoriaItem, depois é só usar assim:

```
CategoriaItem categoria = gson.fromJson("{id:1,cat:teste,icone:icone}", CategoriaItem.class);
```

note que se for uma ocorrencia de json`s voce devera montar um objeto que agrupe as ocorrencias, ele deve ser serializable e a ocorrencia não:

```
public class CategoriaItemArrayList implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<CategoriaItem> categoriaItem;
```

> CategoriaItemArrayList listaCategorias =
>   gson.fromJson("[{id:1,cat:teste,icone:icone},{id:2,cat:teste2,icone:icone2}]",
>   CategoriaItemArrayList.class);

e para acessar o objeto da lista já sabe use o get(0)

```
listaCategorias.get(0);
```